# how to write a matrix with words inside?

Tags: matrices

IN Latex, how to do as title, for example:
[image]

Comment: I don't see any words but  LaTeX math function:  `\cosh`, `\cos`, etc. Please provide what you tray so far that we see where you stack :-) Also from math aspect, your matrix equation is quite strange (at using brackets).

Comment: It's actually having the "\cosh{}" and "\cos{}" :v

Comment: @user - Please note that `\cos`, `\cosh`, etc do not need to get their arguments encased in curly braces.

Comment: Really? I don't see this (sorry but my crystal ball is broken)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose what you call "words", others would call function names, which may be produced easily with `\sin`, `\sinh`, `\cos`, and `\cosh`, respectively.

To create *matrices* encased by square brackets and curly braces, respectively, be sure to load the `amsmath` package and employ its `bmatrix` and `Bmatrix` environments.

Omitting the unnecessary round parentheses, I'd thus write:

```
\documentclass{article} % of some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'bmatrix' and 'Bmatrix' environments
\begin{document}    
 
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cosh \beta L + \cos \beta L & \sinh \beta L + \sin \beta L \\
  \sinh \beta L - \sin \beta L & \cosh \beta L + \cos \beta L 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
  C_1 \\
  C_2
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{Bmatrix}
  0 \\
  0
\end{Bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, so amazing, thanks so much !

Comment: But I expect that OP will show first what OP (s)he try so far ... and than provide  my (already prepared) similar answer :-)

Comment: @Zarko - I suspect the OP got hung up on the subject of writing "words" in the cells of a matrix...

Comment: This should be indicated by my comment. Anyway, you rescue her/him ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I wait with publishing my answer until you show, what you try so far. But @Mico was to fast or conclude, that you will not do this. Anyway, my prepared answer was:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cosh \beta L + \cos \beta L & \sinh \beta L + \sin \beta L \\
  \sinh \beta L - \sin \beta L & \cosh \beta L + \cos \beta L
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
                  C_1 \\
                  C_2
             \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\
      0
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

which to my opinion has more correct matrix notations ...

[image]